# Validating an XML document fails to load schemas referenced with relative paths from within original XSD document

Tags: c, validation, xsd, libxml2

If I start with xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt() the parser is fine and finds all referenced schemas, but I wonder if I can somehow tell it where the schemas are if I use xmlSchemaNewMemParserCtxt().

The thing is, If I already have downloaded XSD in memory can I pass the document URL to the parser so it finds related stuff?

a)

```
char *urlPath = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd";
xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt (urlPath);
```

b)

```
xmlSchemaNewMemParserCtxt (schemaBuffer, buffSize);
```

Variant a) works fine, variant b) produces error
*I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.1.xsd"*

Schemas are located here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably to use XML catalogs, but you can also control loading of sub-resources with `xmlRegisterInputCallbacks` or `xmlSetExternalEntityLoader`.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up from the second variant in the mean time and that is why I'm accepting your answer a bit later :)